# Error while using ListFragement

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I am developing an android app for online payment for which I want to display Lists of restaurants under the tab named Restaurants. Same as this some other tabs will have list below them and a few tabs will have form under them (if possible and not difficult otherwise I will stay with the lists only)

Here is the code I have written. It contains an error in the Adapter class and may be some logical errors which I am not sure about as this is my first ever android app.

Main.java File

```
package com.example.tabswithswipe;
import com.example.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    private String[] tabs = { "Retaurants", "Super Store", "Fuel Stations"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

acivity_main.xml File

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

items_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TabPagerAdapter.java      Adapter File (Error in this file)

```
package com.example.tabsswipe.adapter;
import com.example.tabsswipe.*;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
           return new SuperStoreFragment();
        case 1:
            return new FuelStationsFragment();
        case 2:
            return new RestaurantsFragment();   //Error Here

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

RestaurantsFragment.java

```
package com.example.tabsswipe.adapter;
//import com.example.MainActivity.MyAdapter;
import com.example.tabswithswipe.R;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RestaurantsFragment extends ListFragment {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewGroup container;
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.inflater = inflater;

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, container, false);
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items)));
        return rootView;
     }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] strings) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, container, false);
            String [] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            tv.setText(items[position]);

            if(items[position].equals("kfc"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.kfc);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("pizzaHut"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizzahut);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Domino"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.dominos);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("hardees") )
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.hardees);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("TuttiFrutti"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.tuttifrutti);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("McDonalds"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.mcdonalds);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("21 Street"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }

            return row;
        }

    }
     //   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);

       // return rootView;
   // }



}
```

SuperStoreFragment.java

```
package com.example.tabsswipe.adapter;

import com.example.tabswithswipe.R;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SuperStoreFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_super_stores, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

fragment_super_stores.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fa6a6a" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Design Super Stores Screen"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

FuelStationsFragment.java

```
package com.example.tabsswipe.adapter;
import com.example.tabswithswipe.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FuelStationsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fuel_stations, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

fragment_fuel_stations.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff8400" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Design Fuel Stations Screen"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me how, where and what error occurred. Any kind of help will be really appreciated e.g. Tutorial, code example or even the error resolution of this code. Please ignore my silliness if any. Thank You.

Comment: `Please ignore my silliness if any` i can't, i just can't ... it is compile time error(aka you don't know java) you are using wrong ListFragment(not from support library) as a base of RestaurantsFragment

Comment: What should I use then? I want to display List inside the fragment

Comment: ListFragment from support library ...

Comment: OMG! what have I done. Thank You